# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask about where to buy items?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I wanted to buy a wireless headphone and I have a couple of questions to ask about it.
On which site should I consider posting my question?

Comment: There is not a single forum on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: What's your specific question? If your question is something like "Can I use this sort of wireless headphone with this sort of device" it's on topic, but we can't say "yeah, you should buy X device"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to ask if there is a place for shopping advice questions. As you have seen the answer is no, but many people just ask them anyway.

Answer (score 14):

**None.** Shopping questions are off-topic throughout the Stack Exchange network.

See this blog article for a more thorough discussion of the rationale: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Do note that the Stack Exchange system powers *Q&A sites*, not "forums". That's probably the source of your confusion. Questions here need to be specific, answerable, and useful to other people. If you can imagine people having a long discussion about your question, or that there are multiple correct answers to your question, then it's probably not a good fit around here. All of this is discussed in the FAQ for each site; for example, the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). I do recommend that you read it.

If you really want to associate buying and Stack Exchange, check out the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/), where you can buy cool swag!

Comment: The store is closed! They have replaced it with a zoo containing panda! D: