# Where to ask a question related to keyboard?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On which StackExchange site should I ask about buying items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127570/on-which-stackexchange-site-should-i-ask-about-buying-items)

Can I ask such question in Stack Overflow?

I'm looking for a small ergonomic keyboard that is suitable to programming and preferably has the `ctrl` key on the usual `caps lock` place (to make vim shortcuts easier).
However, I have been unable to find one, even though I did a thorough research on the internet.
So I need to know what other programmers with similar needs use.

Can I ask it on SO, or is there a better stack exchange site to ask this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow [is not about hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). I think [Super User](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) is the best place to ask hardware questions. *However* if it is a shopping question it will be off-topic all over the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic all over Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Mat Forgot, edited accordingly.

Comment: It is indeed kind of a shopping question, but on the other hand, I'm not looking for recommendations, but I just want to know if the described keyboard _exist_.

Comment: @Chiel92: FWIW, I use the Mac OS X keyboard prefs to switch my caps key to CTRL (System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys). Standard features of OS X FTW! :-)

Comment: Currently, I also have it remapped on my ubuntu. But it'd be cool if it's already in the keyboard layout, since it'd work on any system by default. However, it's not a must-have.